# Fastest Way to Find Maximum Value in A Range

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to find the highest value in a range of a column in a dataframe.

The following works but is very slow.

```
df.loc[5:15, 'Score'].max()
```

Is there a way of speeding it up? If it matters, it is possible that there may be multiple Scores that are the maximum but I only need to return one.

Example df extract (the actual df has many more columns):

| Subject | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Maths | 22 |
| Maths | 21 |
| Maths | 22 |
| Maths | 19 |
| Maths | 19 |
| Maths | 19 |
| Maths | 23 |
| Maths | 21 |
| Maths | 25 |
| Maths | 22 |
| Maths | 23 |
| Maths | 22 |
| Maths | 20 |
| Maths | 19 |
| Maths | 19 |
| Maths | 19 |
| Maths | 24 |
| Maths | 21 |
| Maths | 22 |
| Maths | 24 |

Expected result:

25

Comment: How about using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)?

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame('maths', index=range(0, 10000000), columns=['subject'])
df['score'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000000)
```

df:

[image]

10,000,000 rows example

---

**Code**

lets find 20~99980 row's max

```
df.loc[20:99980, 'score'].max()
```

output;

```
99
```

chk time

```
%timeit df.loc[20:99980, 'score'].max()
```

result:

```
182 µs ± 653 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

it take only 0.000182 second.

I cannot reproduce the fact that it takes a long time. Question is valid only if we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Need further detail on what about this is slow.

If I convert the slice to numpy then same operation is faster, but now convenience of the dataframe is gone.

```
df = pd.DataFrame('maths', index=range(0, 10000000), columns=['subject'])
df['score'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000000)

df.loc[20:99980, 'score'].max()

99

%timeit df.loc[20:99980, 'score'].max()

122 µs ± 856 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

a = df.loc[20:99980, 'score'].to_numpy()

a[a.argmax()]

99

%%timeit 
a[a.argmax()]

15.4 µs ± 190 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with efficient code is related to the number of columns in your dataframe.  The time complexity of the solution is dependent on both the number of rows as well as the number of columns being filtered.  To illustrate this issue, take a 5 column dataframe with 100 rows.

using timeit we can show that the time to extract the maximum value from rows 15: 50 is as follows:

```
%%timeit
df.loc[5:50, 'Score'].max()
```

yields:
91 µs ± 5.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

By first filtering on the desired column this time can be reduced as follows:

```
%%timeit
df['Score'].iloc[5:50].max()
```

Yields:
62.9 µs ± 7.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

By using the speed of numpy this process can be reduces to the following:

```
%%timeit
df['Score'].to_numpy()[5:50].max()
```

yields:
7.31 µs ± 568 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

But surprisingly, the best time is achieved by the following:

```
%%timeit
max(df['Score'].to_list()[5:50])
```

Yields:
6.39 µs ± 474 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)